# How to get Android Context using Robolectric 4.3.1

Tags: android-context, robolectric

Trying to use Robolectric 4.3.1 to do the most basic of Android actions, get the Context.

I get a non-null context by doing this (tried many other attempts but all end up getting context = null):

```
Context context  = RuntimeEnvironment.systemContext;
```

I can pass the object into some methods but I can never use it.

If I try

```
File dir = context.getFilesDir();
```

I get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No data directory found for package android
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class BtScannerTests
{
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        bluetoothAdapter = Shadow.newInstanceOf(BluetoothAdapter.class);
    }

    private static boolean done = false;
    @Test
    public void testBtScannerCycle() throws InterruptedException
    {
        IntermediaryCallback intermediaryCallback = new IntermediaryCallback()
        {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveMdsIntermediary(MdsIntermediary mds, int connectionHandle)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceiveMetricIntermediaries(List<MetricIntermediary> metricList, MdsIntermediary mds, int connectionHandle)
        {

        }
        };

        StatusEventCallback statusEventCallback = new StatusEventCallback()
        {
        @Override
        public void onStatusEvent(StatusEvent statusEvent, int connectionHandle, String btAddress)
        {
            System.out.println("Status event " + statusEvent.name());
            if(statusEvent == StatusEvent.SCANNING_PAUSED);
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        };

        Context context  = RuntimeEnvironment.systemContext;
        File dir = context.getFilesDir();  // This is the code that fails; put here to test attempts
        AndroidBtManager.setStatusEventCallback(statusEventCallback);
        AndroidBtManager androidBtManager =
            new AndroidBtManager(context, intermediaryCallback, false, false, true);
        BtScanner btScanner = androidBtManager.getBtScanner();
        while(!done)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one.

```
Context context  = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
```

instead of

```
Context context  = RuntimeEnvironment.systemContext;
```

Comment: Thank you. I stumbled upon the answer (forget how). That's an Androidx thing as I understand it.

Comment: How can I import `ApplicationProvider`?

Comment: @anticafe use the latest robolectric version.